# ActionListener Loops back on itself

Tags: java, actionlistener

Well, I actually feel stupid for even asking this question but: Is it possible for an ActionListener to loop back on it self? The situation is as follows (kind shorthandish because it is a lot of in itself sound code that does nothing to the problem)

```
JMenuItem Menu=new JMenuItem();
Menu.addActionListener(e -> {
            JDialog Dialog=new JDialog();
            JTextField Name= new JTextField("",30);
            JFormattedTextField ID =new JFormattedTextField(NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance());
            ID.setColumns(8);
            JButton Enter=new JButton();
            \\GUI building stuff
            Enter.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    Integer ImportID=((Number) ID.getValue()).intValue();
                    String ImportName= Name.getText();
                    System.out.println("Eingaben\n"+ImportID);
                    System.out.println(ImportName);
                    //loads of different stuff
                    Dialog.dispose();
                    System.out.println(ImportID);
                    System.out.println(ImportName);
                    //ID.setValue(null);
                    //Name.setText(null);
                    //ImportID=null;
                    //ImportID=null;
                    System.out.println("Fertig!");
                }
            });
           
});
```

Now this menu leads to a dialog intended as an import dialog. What happens now is that the first time any user input data is used this data is propagated correctly. But if the user attempts make a input a second time the **first** and the second values are handed through - even with the disposing of the Dialog the data of the first go through shouldn't even be accessible, right?
I tried replacing the inner ActionListener with an e.getSource, which didn't work. Setting the variables or the Field to null doesn't help either.
I am aware that placing an ActionListener within an ActionListener is propably bad form.

**Edit:** I should explain how this works: The MenuItem (which sits inside the menubar of a proper GUI) is selected and calls forth a Dialog where the user enters two pieces of data and selects some files. Selected files are copied into a new directory and the entered data is processed into two text files. After that happened the Dialog is set to invisible and some different and to the data unrelated processing occurs. This processign being finished things are supposed to be wrapped up so that the dialog can be called upon again. If however I close the application this error does not occur.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking (or doing) with the `new JDialog()` which creates a dialog and then you dispose it in the `Enter` action listener, but there are no other references to it anywhere else; it's local to the `Menu` action listener.

Comment: My guess is that you are adding the same `ActionListener` to either `Menu` or `Enter`. Method [getActionListeners](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#getActionListeners()) will return all the added [action] listeners so that you can check if my guess is correct. If I am correct then I suggest that you integrate method [removeActionListener](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#removeActionListener(java.awt.event.ActionListener)) to ensure only having a single listener added.

Comment: If you add the same `ActionListener` twice, then it will execute twice.

Comment: I don't know if the code in your question is your actual code or just some "quick-and-dirty" code that you wrote in order to demonstrate your problem. If it is your actual code, I think that creating GUI components in an anonymous inner class may be the cause of your problem. Since `ActionListener` is a [functional interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html) I prefer to implement it via [method references](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html).

Comment: @Abra how do I avoid the scond calling? And yes it is some quick-and-dirty code that should provide the problem. made it after I ruled out a ton of other sources for this error.

Comment: _how do I avoid the scond calling?_ Based on the [lack of] code in your question, I suggest simply removing all the listeners immediately before you add one. Note however that you only want to remove the listeners that you added. I guess you could check the actual class of the `ActionListener` in order to see if it is one that you added.

Comment: Removing the actionlistener helped, tahnk you!